# “Unauthorized actions have been detected. Restart your phone to undo any unauthorized changes.” notification on Samsung device

Tags: notifications, security, samsung

I have a new Samsung Galaxy A3 that keeps on giving me a security notice saying

> Unauthorized actions have been detected. Restart your phone to undo any unauthorized changes.

How do I stop receiving these notices?

Comment: There is an app in google play you can download to fix this error https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=disable.securitylogagent.com.securitylogagentfix&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Direct-copy from [Samsung Knox official support](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/faq/my-device-displayed-notification-%E2%80%9Cunauthorized-actions-have-been-detected-restart-your-phone):

> **My device displayed the notification: “Unauthorized actions have been detected. Restart your phone to undo any unauthorized changes.” What do I do?**
>
> During regular security checks of the Linux kernel, the system has detected that the kernel has been modified. Possible causes:
>
> - You may have installed a malicious or flawed app, which attempted to modify the kernel code or file system
> - You may have accidentally removed or modified a system file.
>
> One of these messages will appear: "To protect your device. It is recommended you reboot." or "The device has detected an application attempting to perform actions that are not permitted. It is recommended that you restart your device."
>
> Restart your device to try to restore the kernel code back to normal. However, some kernel modifications made to the file system cannot be restored. Also, the original cause of the problem might still persist. Therefore, you might continue to see this error after the reboot.
>
> If issues continue to persist, contact the [Global Customer Support center](http://www.samsung.com/global/support/globalcontact.html) and provide details of the error.

It's suggested that restarting the device may fix the issue, but not always (and since you mentioned "keeps on", it seems this didn't fix the issue). So, you have some alternatives:

1. Contact [their customer support](http://www.samsung.com/global/support/globalcontact.html) and explain it (as recommended by Samsung)
2. If your device is still under warranty (assuming you really didn't do anything to the device), consider to request for device replacement.
3. If there is no other choice, try doing factory reset and see if it helps. Otherwise, you might need to reflash it with stock ROM & working kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Often it's because you have a rooted phone and you have granted access to some application to mess with root files KNOX are protecting, such as the kernel. My idea is that system apps can with change root files without problem.

What did to fix it:

1. SuperSU -> setting -> clear log
2. Install SuperSU to `/system` using the settings option